# How can I test a bash script for setting up a new machine

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, scripting

I have a couple bash scripts to automate the setup process for a new devices e.g. installing packages, configuring environment variables, etc.

I'm working on making the process more automated with autoexpect, and adding a few thing other things; however, it's difficult to test since every time I run the install script I have to manually go back an undo the changes that were made from running the script. Is there a way to run the scripts without actually installing anything so I can observe the behaviour for testing? something like the `--dry-run` option with rsync

Comment: All Expect cares about is *output*. You can simulate the whole setup process with a script.

Comment: Personally I would not count on `autoexpect` for any serious work. :)

Comment: Show [some code](/help/how-to-ask). What's the package manager used?

Answer (score 0):

for configuring your machine and being able to test this quickly and knowing you won't cause problems to your PC locally, create a VM using Virtual box or VMwWare player and then snapshot the VM so you can revert back to the state before you run the script, and then you can run your script on this VM, and check what configuration has been applied successfully.